# Is it possible to style multiple Plot or ListPlot curves using a color gradient?

Tags: plotting, color

I am using Mathematica 8.  In Mathematica, there is a default `PlotStyle` coloring in `Plot` and `ListPlot`.  For example, suppose I have a series of nine functions stored in the list `functions`.  Mathematica styles the different curves in a cyclic way (I think that the default is cycles of **"blue", purple, dark yellow, green**), as in this example:

```
functions = Table[a*Cos[x], {a, 0.2, 1, 0.1}]
Plot[functions, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> ```
> {0.2 Cos[x], 0.3 Cos[x], 0.4 Cos[x], 0.5 Cos[x], 0.6 Cos[x], 0.7 Cos[x], 0.8 Cos[x],
>  0.9 Cos[x], 1. Cos[x]}
> ```
>
> [image: plot1]

This is nice, but now suppose that I want to color the multiple curves using some sort of gradient (perhaps one of the gradients in `ColorData`).  Is this possible in `Plot` and `ListPlot`?

I could do this somewhat manually.  For example, if I wanted a blue gradient, I could write the following (although this choice of colors could somehow be improved):

```
Plot[functions, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {
   Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Blue]]]],
   Lighter[Lighter[Lighter[Blue]]],
   Lighter[Lighter[Blue]],
   Lighter[Blue],
   Blue,
   Darker[Blue],
   Darker[Darker[Blue]],
   Darker[Darker[Darker[Blue]]],
   Darker[Darker[Darker[Darker[Blue]]]]
   }]
```

> [image: plot2]

However, this becomes complicated if I have many curves or if I want to use a more complex gradient such as rainbow (e.g., `ColorData["Rainbow"]`), temperature map (e.g., `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]`), etc.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is this ok or You want more automatic option? `Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[x] + t, {t, 0, 1, .1}], {x, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Table[Blend[{White, Blue, Black}, i], {i, 0, 1, .1}]]` Blend works also with palletes. `Blend["Rainbow",x]`

Comment: @Kuba This is nice!  Thank you!  I just need to scale with respect to the number of curves, perhaps using `Table[i/Length[functions], {i, 1, Length[functions]}]`, as halirutan does below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One pretty easy thing is to create a table of the gradient colors directly inside the `Plot`. The only thing you need to take care of is the scaling. All the color gradients take values between [0,1] when you access `ColorData["GradientName",x]`. Therefore, you need to now the number of your functions:

```
functions = Table[a*Cos[x], {a, 0.2, 1, 0.1}]
Plot[functions, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
   Table[ColorData["Rainbow", i/(Length[functions]-1)], {i,0, Length[functions]-1}]
]
```

[image]

If you want a sneak preview for all color schemes, you can quickly hack some `Manipulate`

[image]

```
With[{
  control = (ColorData[#, "ColorFunction"] -> 
            Show[ColorData[#, "Image"], ImageSize -> 90]) & /@ ColorData["Gradients"],
  fns = Table[a*Cos[x], {a, 0.2, 1, 0.1}]},
  Manipulate[
   Plot[fns, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotStyle -> 
     Table[s@Rescale[c, {1, Length[fns]}, {cmin, cmax}], {c, 
       Length[fns]}]],
   {{s, control[[1, 1]], "Color Scheme"}, control},
   {{cmin, 0, "Color Min"}, 0, cmax},
   {{cmax, 1, "Color Max"}, .1, 1}
   ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is just a thought... instead of using `Table[ColorData["Rainbow", i/Length[functions]], {i, Length[functions]}]`, another possibility might be `Table[ColorData["Rainbow", i], {i, 0, 1, 1/(Length[functions] - 1)}]`.  Whereas `Table[i/Length[functions], {i, Length[functions]}]` gives `{1/9, 2/9, 1/3, 4/9, 5/9, 2/3, 7/9, 8/9, 1}`, `Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 1/(Length[functions] - 1)}]` gives `{0, 1/8, 1/4, 3/8, 1/2, 5/8, 3/4, 7/8, 1}`.  Thank you so much for your time and detailed and excellent help!

Comment: @Andrew Hehe, yes you are right. I was about to edit the answer shortly, but I'm preparing something else I want to include ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In a modern versions You can use just `PlotStyle->"Rainbow"` or any other gradient or color list; gradient will be already scaled to all plots and color list will be looped if there is insufficient numbers of colors inside:

```
functions = Table[a*Cos[x], {a, 0.2, 1, 0.1}]
Table[Plot[functions, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> i], {i, {"Rainbow", "BeachColors", "DarkBands","Pastel", ColorData[42]}}]
```

[image]

However, it is not stretched in case of `Physical` gradients since their range is different from `{0,1}`:

```
Table[Plot[functions, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> i], {i, {"BlackBodySpectrum","VisibleSpectrum","HypsometricTints"}}]
```

[image]